# Finding nth inorder node of a binary tree where each node contains number of left nodes in its subtree

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

I came across this problem and can't seem to find a solution for it anywhere.

> Given a binary tree where each node contains a number denoting the amount of left nodes
>   in its subtree, write a function that returns the nth inorder
>   traversal node.

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.leftNodes = 0
```

Finding the [nth node of inorder traversal](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-n-th-node-inorder-traversal/) is fairly trivial, but how can I use the information about number of left nodes to improve the process?

Comment: See e.g. this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38985145/count-number-of-smaller-values-while-inserting-into-binary-search-tree-bst/38985607#38985607

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @m69 gave the hint - you can use the left-node count to avoid some un-necessary steps.

Assume having tree where the root have 10 nodes in his left sub-tree: then when asking for node n-th (when in-order) then if `n= 1-10` then the answer will be in the left sub-tree. However if `n= 11` then answer will be the root, else the answer will be in the right sub-tree.

Consider the following pseudo code:

```
findNnode(TreeNode root, int n) {
    if (root.leftNodes + 1 == n )
        return root; 
    if (root.leftNodes <= n)
        return findNnode(root.left, n)
    newN = n - root.leftNodes - 1; // after substract all node who came before in in-order
    return findNnode(root.right, newN)
}
```

Hope that helps!